# What would be Solr field type in Solr schema for Cassandra map type field

Tags: solr, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, solrcloud

I have a cassandra table like :-

```
create table t1(a int PRIMARY KEY, b map<int, int>);
```

Now I have to import this table into Solr, So what would be field type in Solr for field 'b'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/addMapField.html

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to store in the multi-value field. As you can see "map" type field is not supported in solr.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/aboutFields.html

```
doc {
  b : [ 1, 2]
  ...
}
```